# event receiver modified user

Tags: sharepoint-server, event-receivers

I have an event receiver to capture the editor of an updated item.

```
string Editor = properties.ListItem["Editor"].ToString().Trim();
```

From the above code i can get the user name. But I want the active directory user id.

How can I get it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: why do you want the id of the user from AD? what if there are two or three or four Jon Smiths?

Comment: No, I want the user ID, not the user's name. from the code above i get the user's name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

still dont know why you want this as its not unique. you can do the following:

```
SPUser editor = new SPFieldUserValue(properties.Web, properties.ListItem["Editor"].ToString()).User;

string Editor = editor.ID;
```

its not the AD ID but the sitecollection user ID. to get AD user ID you need to query AD specifically using ldap or other means. like:

```
private UserPrincipal GetUser(String samAccountName)
{

    PrincipalContext principalContext = GetPrincipalContext;

    return UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, samAccountName);

}

private UserPrincipal GetUser(String displayName)
{

    PrincipalContext principalContext = GetPrincipalContext;

    return UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, IdentityType.DisplayName, samAccountName);

}

private UserPrincipal GetUser(String identity, IdentityType identityType)
{

    PrincipalContext principalContext = GetPrincipalContext;

    return UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, identityType, identity);

}
```

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19115.sharepoint-querying-active-directory-using-c-net.aspx

how to use above:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344891(v=vs.110).aspx

as an example:

```
UserPrincipal getUser = GetUser(properties.ListItem["Editor"].ToString().Trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing the following.

```
SPUser user = null;
string[] data = username.Split(new string[] { ";#" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
SPPrincipalInfo pinfo = SPUtility.ResolvePrincipal(web, data[1], SPPrincipalType.User, SPPrincipalSource.All, web.Users, false);
user = web.Users[pinfo.LoginName];
string[] unames = pinfo.LoginName.Split(new string[] { @"|xxxxx\" },StringSplitOptions.None);
string username = unames[1];
```